# How can I add mouse listener to graphics Polygon?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I want to add a mousse listener to this polygon. How can I add mouse listener to graphics `Polygon`?

```
public class Domx extends JPanel{

    Domx(){
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        Polygon p4=new Polygon();
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
                p4.addPoint((int) (X + i * P4[9] / 2), (int) (Y + P1[10] + P2[10] + P3[10] + P4[10]));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i > -2; i--) {
            p4.addPoint((int) (X + i * P4[8] / 2), (int) (Y + P1[10] + P2[10] + P3[10]));
        }
        g2.fillPolygon(p4);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you wan to achieve with the mouse listener?

Comment: *I wanna add a mousse listener to this polygon.*  -You can't do this directly. You can only add a MouseListener to a component. See Andrew's answer. If you want to get fancy check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for the `ShapeComponent` class which allows you to create a component with the Shape of your Polygon.

Answer (score 1):

A `MouseListener` is added to components, which a `Polygon` is .. not. 
Instead add the mouse listener to the component which displays it, then when a mouse action happens, check if `polygon.contains(..)` before proceeding.